# Calculate run time as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, runtime

So I'm making rather a complicated AI. I'd like to calculate my processing time. Is there anybody can help me with a appropriate code.

NOTE: I rely heavily on timeline (frames). The run time calculation start in one frame but stops at many various frame, depends on scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flash.utils.getTimer()`.

`getTimer()` returns the milliseconds that have elapsed since the Flash started.

For example

```
import flash.utils.getTimer;

var startTime:uint = getTimer();

...some code...

var endTime:uint = getTimer();

trace("time : " + (endTime-startTime));
```